# Maximum order statistic for Binomial distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, order-statistics

Let $X_i$, $1\le i\le t$, be $t$ independent random variables with Binomial distribution $B(n,\frac1t)$.

I would like to find the distribution of $X_{Max}=\max_{i=1}^t(X_i)$

Note that this is the specific case where the probability of success is equal to the reciprocal of the number of variables I am taking the maximum over.

I expect that the answer will be too complex to use directly, so an approximation would be good to have. In fact just having an approximate formula for $\mathbb{E}(X_{Max})$ and $\mathbb{Var}(X_{Max})$ would be sufficient, and I am most interested in the case where $n\gg t\gg1$.

Answer (score 4):

Despite considerable upvoted interest in the question itself, ... this question has remained unanswered for over 4 months.

We are given $X$ ~ Binomial$(n,p)$ with pmf $f(x)$:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/binomialpmff.png))</sub>

Let $(X_1, ..., X_t)$ denote a random sample of size $t$ drawn on $X$. Then, the pmf of the $t$-th order statistic (*i.e.* the pmf of the sample maximum), denoted say $g(x)$, is given by:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/samplemaxpmfbinomialparent.png))</sub>

where `OrderStat[t, f, samplesize]` is a `mathStatica` function that finds the pmf of the $t$-th order statistic, and where the `Hypergeometric2F1` is [described here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html) . The domain of support is, of course:

`domain[g] = {x, 0, n}`

This solution, for general probability parameter $p$, nests the special case the original poster wishes to solve for, namely where $p=\frac{1}{t}$. So simply plug in: $p=\frac{1}{t}$.

Normally, of course, as the sample size (here $t$) increases, the distribution of the sample maximum shifts out to the right. However, in this particular set-up, because $p=\frac{1}{t}$, the opposite happens ... the distribution of the sample maximum shifts to the left as $t$ increases, as the following plot illustrates:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tri.org.au](http://www.tri.org.au/se/plotsamplemax.png))</sub>

[I have also 'checked' the above solution using Monte Carlo methods: all seems fine. ]